# detecting deprecated functions in C++

Tags: c++, doxygen, deprecated

In a C++ project documented with Doxygen, I have marked some functions as \deprecated in the Doxygen comments. Is there any way to use these comments (with Doxygen or another tool) in order to detect that another non-deprecated function is calling a deprecated one ? (The project is pretty big and going through all the classes would take a lot of time).

Thanks

Comment: This is slightly error-prone because of overload resolution, so not an answer, but most of the time you can get the answer you want by removing all the deprecated functions (e.g. using a macro `REMOVE_DEPRECATED`), then build your source :-) If fails to report some uses, for example if `void foo(char)` is deprecated but `void foo(int)` isn't, and a non-deprecated function calls `foo('a')`.

Comment: Geoff_Montee: mostly GCC (4.6)

Comment: Okay, I was going to recommend what @honk suggested.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using GCC or clang to compile your code you could manually annotate functions.

```
__attribute__((__deprecated__))
void dep_fun() { }
```

Then *calling* `dep_fun` anywhere in your code will emit a diagnostic message.

If you placed doxygen's `\deprecated` annotation consistently you should be able to update the code automatically with tools like sed.

Comment: For Visual Studio you would use [`__declspec(deprecated)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/044swk7y(v=VS.80).aspx) e.g. `__declspec(deprecated) void dep_fun() { }`.

Comment: Thanks honk, does your solution reports something at run-time or at compile-time ? (I'm looking for a compile-time warning)

Comment: It's a compile time warning. See: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function%20Attributes (search for "deprecated")

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried and it's just what I need. Yet I get warnings when a deprecated function calls another deprecated one. I guess I'll have to deal with it.

Comment: @sumat: the reason for those warnings is that the compiler doesn't know whether you'll remove the deprecated functions one at a time or all at once. So as far as it's concerned, a deprecated function calling another one is just a dangerous (and deserves a warning) as a non-deprecated function calling a deprecated one. It would probably be nice to have fine control of that, though.

Answer (score 3):

Building on Benjamins answer:
Some useful compiler directives:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define DEPRECATED __declspec(deprecated)
#elif defined(__GNUC__) | defined(__clang__)
#define DEPRECATED __attribute__((__deprecated__))
#else
#define DEPRECATED
#endif

//usage:
DEPRECATED void foo(int bar);
```

(warning: untested under clang and msc, only tested on GNUC.)

Comment: Oh good, they all go in the same place in the syntax!  I know there's at least one (forceinline?) where they go in different places in each compiler.